# Can you Correct this Integral of Trigs?

Tags: integration

Someone told me

$$
2g\int_{0}^{\arcsin\left(\frac{r}{g}\right)}dx\cos\left(x\right)\sqrt{r^{2}-g^{2}\sin^{2}\left(x\right)}=\frac{\pi}{2}g^2\
$$
but I'm sure they're wrong. Can anyone help? Note Mathematica gives me a singularity at the upper limit. Perhaps

$$
2g\int_{0}^{\arcsin\left(\frac{r}{g}\right)}dx\cos\left(x\right)\sqrt{r^{2}-g^{2}\sin^{2}\left(x\right)}=\frac{\pi}{2}r^{2}\
$$

is correct?

Answer (score 1):

The substitution $u=g\sin(x)$ turns the integral into

$$2\int_0^r\sqrt{r^2-u^2}\,du$$

so yes, you're right, it should be an $r$ instead of a $g$.

Comment: doesn't the integral have an arctan(r/0) at the upper limit?

Comment: OK if we assume r>0 its ok

Comment: @AlexanderGiles, the upper limit, $\arcsin(r/g)$, only makes sense if $|r|\le |g|$.